# How to use the Position output of a Voronoi Texture Node?

Tags: texturing, materials

Pretty self explanatory.

Though the background for the question is that I was making a procedural brick path texture with a semi circle arch pattern (still do not know how the pattern is called in real life masonry). Figured out how to create lines of circles, cut them in half, offset for each other line in one direction only, add them together, use them as mask and vector for the brick texture. Eventually I figured voronoi is not very good for making the "spokes" of the "brick wheel" because the vector only follow the distance from a point's center like a sphere, not like a circle (hope it makes sense). Eventually found the Position Output of the node and thought, if it is what I think it is, I could center each iteration of the pattern on the position of each point of the voronoi texture.

[image]

Comment: Voronoi is the distance from the nearest, randomish-point; position is the position of that nearest point.  If you want it to act like circles (cylinders) instead of spheres, set the Voronoi to 2D instead of 3D.

Comment: @Nathan Just checked, it's set up as 2D, F1, Euclidian. Making it 2D does make it work like a cylinder but more like an onion slice, what I want is it to work like a lemon slice, so something in-between 3D and 2D...? Or somehow use voronoi's point positions on some other texture's vector, like origins

Comment: @Nathan If still interested, found some better way to make the effect. We use Tex.Coord."Obj"> Maping> Sep. XYZ> Math"Modulo"2> 3Math"Wrap"max-1min1;max2min0;max-1min1> Comb.XYZ> Grad.Tex."Radial" and Vec.Math"Distance0,0,0> Comb.XYZ> "Vector"Brick Tex. That is the jist of things, there's more to it, making a mask for each layer of round, tiled brick texture but the comment have no much space. Still do not know how to propperly use the voronoi node's position though. To me seems like a redundancy of Color output so far